# Cookie is not getting set on browser

Tags: node.js, cookies, jwt, http-headers, setcookie

I am working on a `nodejs` backend and `react` front-end application with `jwt` authentication features. When authenticating users I need to send cookies to the client via `Set-cookie header`. It works fine when I use localhost, but after deploying it on `render` it does not work. The cookies are not getting saved. On the network tab, it gives a warning `This attempt to set a cookie via Set-cookie header was blocked because its Domain attribute was invalid with regard to the current host url`.

Network tab

[image]

Cookies in response

[image]

This is my cookie configuration file

```
import urls from './urls.js';

const { hostname } = new URL(urls.CLIENT_URL);
const domain = `.${hostname.split('.').slice(-2).join('.')}`; //.onrender.com

const access = {
    name: process.env.COOKIE_ACCESS_NAME,
    options: {
        sameSite: 'none',
        domain,
        httpOnly: false,
        secure: true,
        maxAge: process.env.ACCESS_EXP,
    },
    delete: {
        sameSite: 'none',
        domain,
        httpOnly: false,
        secure: true,
        maxAge: new Date(null),
    },
};

const refresh = {
    name: process.env.COOKIE_REFRESH_NAME,
    options: {
        sameSite: 'none',
        domain,
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        maxAge: process.env.REFRESH_EXP,
    },
    delete: {
        sameSite: 'none',
        domain,
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        maxAge: new Date(null),
    },
};

export default { access, refresh };
```

Here, I have changed the domain `const` to

- https://docapp-client-blind.onrender.com/
- [docapp-client-blind.onrender.com](https://docapp-client-blind.onrender.com/)
- .onrender.com
- onrender.com

(Haved typed manually to check on `const domain = domain-name`)

Noting works. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

Server running on docapp-blind.onrender.com cannot directly set cookie on docapp-client.onrender.com. In your backend cookie setting configuration change the value of domain to onrender.com.

[image]

In the above picture you can see the domain on the both the set-cookie is https://docapp-client-blind.onrender.com. change this value from backend to .onrender.com

Comment: I have already tried them, read my post. I am adding screenshots to help you understand [link](https://imgur.com/a/Sh63ZAC)